# TypeError: t(...).on is not a function on fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

fullcalendar is throwing an error:

> TypeError: t(...).on is not a function fullcalendar.min.js:8:11264

This are my script/css includes:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.3.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.3.1/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.3.1/fullcalendar.print.css " rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

And this is the page where I want to use fullcalendar:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {

        // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            // put your options and callbacks here
        })

    });
</script>
```

Very basic, I just used the code from the documentation page. So my guess is that I've done something wrong with the  tags.

Edit: I changed to use the non-minified version of fullcalendar.
The error message changed to:

> TypeError: $(...).on is not a function fullcalendar.js:6912:2

When I click on that error it shows:

```
$(document).on('mousedown', this.documentMousedownProxy);
```

In the function:

```
bindGlobalHandlers: function() {
    $(document).on('mousedown', this.documentMousedownProxy);
},
```

Comment: use the non-minified version of the plugin for a better error message.

Comment: But even without that, the error is clearly $.fn.on is undefined, which is expected with the version of jQuery you are using. Upgrade jquery, or downgrade the plugin.

Comment: I have changed to the non-minified version.
I will upgrade jquery to test.

Answer (score 1):

The comment of Kevin B was the solution.
I had to upgrade my jquery version.

I changed the jquery script to `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` and it works.